# Django + MySQL, form/create mysql query to pass a valid argument to the url

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to django need help, where trying to build inventory tool with (Django==1.4), which would be easily fetch the list of hosts/servers from database(MySQL)

What I am suppose to achieve is to simply provide the hostname as argument with url and fetch it into django application, build query and show the results on to UI.

Example URL: http://test.example.com/gethost/?hostname=localhost

== urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^gethost', 'dc.views.gethost', name='gethost'),
```

== views.py:

```
def gethost(request, hostname, template_file="gethost.html"):
  from django.db import connection, transaction
  hostname = request.GET.get('hostname')
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE hosts='%s'" % 'hostname')
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
  t = Context({'results': rows})
  return render_to_response(template_file, t)
```

mysql cmd:

```
[root@localhost dc]# mysql dc -e 'SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE hosts="localhost"'
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
| id | groups    | hosts     | loc  |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
|  1 | localhost | localhost |  sf  |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Why are you directly using MySQL statements rather than the ORM?

Comment: Ian Clark, how do i play around it, since these are the heavily use and queried about to 10000 hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for you timely help..

@eddwinpaz, it got fixed in views

== views.py:

```
def gethost(request, hostname, template_file="gethost.html"):
  from django.db import connection, transaction
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE hosts='%s'" % hostname)
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
  t = Context({'results': rows})
  return render_to_response(template_file, t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not passing anything and recomended to use ORM instead of SQL based.

```
url(r'^gethost/(?P<hostname>[\w\-]+)/$', 'dc.views.gethost'),
```

Comment: thanks, in this case how do I call url to form/build a query?

Comment: should be www.domain.com/gethost/anothersite.com

Comment: Yeah, tried one, that does not gives me output to read db...

@eddwinpaz, it might be the issue at views

Comment: thanks for your help, did fix this in views also your urls help to get the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code below hope it makes more clear of what you want to achieve. make sure on your settings.py there is the URL for the TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('var/www/dc/templates/') in your case use the path on your system on settings.py. also make sure on INSTALLED_APPS is 'dc' added.

## settings.py

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('var/www/dc/templates/')

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, render_to_response
from dc.models import inventory

def gethost(request, hostname):

   try:
       inventory_data = inventory.objets.get(hostname=hostname)
       return render(request,'gethost.html',{inventory:'inventory_data'})

   except inventory.DoesNotExist:

         return HttpResponseRedirect('/myurl/') 
         # this is a dummy url you must set it to a 404 if you want
```

## gethost.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2>View Hostname: {{inventory.hostname}}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

## models.py

from django.db import models

class inventory(models.Model):

```
hostname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.hostname
```